# What are the advantages of splitting a WCF service solution into 2 assemblies, 1 for the contracts and 1 for the implementation?

Tags: .net, wcf, architecture

[**This**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51063/Setting-up-a-Project-framework-for-a-WCF-Solution) article suggests splitting a WCF service solution into 2 projects, 1 for the contracts assembly and 1 for the implementation assembly.

Why is this advantageous? What do I stand to gain from this split? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious advantage is you can share service contract dll file to your client. When you share a common service contract dll between the client and the server, your client can use the service with the `ChannelFactory` class.

```
ChannelFactory<IHelloWorld> channel = new ChannelFactory<IHelloWorld>("tcp");
```

*(Two different ways WCF Service can be consumed by client. ([Using ChannelFactory Vs. Proxies in WCF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/juveriak/archive/2008/02/03/using-channels-vs-proxies-in-wcf.aspx))*

Comment: +1 ahh yes, that makes sense since I prefer to programatically bind the client to the server, rather than use those wretched app.config files.

Answer (score 1):

In general (not specifically for WCF services) it is considered good practice from a design point of view to separate your interfaces from the implementation.

However, with WCF services you have to be careful with this: If the interface project includes interfaces of objects that are used by the service methods, then the WCF service interfaces should not be part of the interface project but be defined in the implementation project. The reason for this is that WCF service operations should not use interface types in their method signatures because interface types can not be serialized (in an interoperable way). They should use implementation types and therefore they should be part of the implementation project, because otherwise you would need to add a reference from your interface project to your implementation project. That would be poor design and would make the separation of interface from implementation useless.

Comment: Thanks, so do you know of a better way to setup a "WCF Framework", whatever that's supposed to mean. Is there something lacking in the way the WCF Service Library project template does it? If that article is not the right way, then what is the better way? Any resources would be appreciated.

Comment: @Sam I don't think there is a one-size-fits-all way. WCF can be used in many different ways and for many different purposes. In your case I would just start with the most simple way and search for more appropriate designs that fit you specific needs when necessary.